# How to center align logo image and right align navigation ul

Tags: css, alignment, centering

Both the logo and navigation are in a header div and I'd like to have the logo centered while the navigation is aligned to the right.

I've tried doing display:block and margin: auto for the image which gets it centered, but then it pushes the navigation down to the next line.

Current css is:

```
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Navigation */

#nav {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto; 
    padding:0; 
    list-style:none;
    float: right;
}
```

Read that I had to put width in to make margin:auto work but all it does is enlarges the image. Thanks.

Comment: Would help greatly to post an image of what you were looking for (can link it through min.us or something of the like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float` from your `#nav` & define `text-align:center` to it's parent. Write like this:

```
.header{
 text-align:center;
}
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px
}

/* Navigation */

#nav {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0; 
    list-style:none;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I got it to work with the header center align and adding in position absolute for the nav.